# Spring 3+ How to create a TestSuite when JUnit is not recognizing it

Tags: spring, junit, testing, suite

I'm using Spring 3.0.4 and JUnit 4.5. My test classes currently uses Spring's annotation test support with the following syntax:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration (locations = { "classpath:configTest.xml" })
@TransactionConfiguration (transactionManager = "txManager", defaultRollback = true)
@Transactional
public class MyAppTest extends TestCase 

{
 @Autowired
 @Qualifier("myAppDAO")
 private IAppDao appDAO;
    ...
}
```

I don't really need the line **extends TestCase** to run this test. It's not needed when running this test class by itself. I had to add **extends TestCase** so that I can add it in a TestSuite class:

```
public static Test suite() {
        TestSuite suite = new TestSuite("Test for app.dao");
  //$JUnit-BEGIN$
  suite.addTestSuite(MyAppTest.class);
        ...
```

If I omit the **extends TestCase**, my Test Suite will not run. Eclipse will flag **suite.addTestSuite(MyAppTest.class)** as error.

How do I add a Spring 3+ test class to a Test Suite? I'm sure there's a better way. I've GOOGLED and read the docs. If you don't believe me, I'm willing to send you all my bookmarks as proof. But in any case, I would prefer a constructive answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: LOL. I googled again and saw my question on the Google results. I'm gonna search again :)

Comment: Rod Johnson himself wrote, "Spring itself has an excellent unit test suite" (http://www.theserverside.com/news/1363858/Introduction-to-the-Spring-Framework). Where is this excellent test suite documented?

Comment: The url you gave doesnot work!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right; JUnit4-style tests should not extend `junit.framework.TestCase`

You can include a JUnit4 test as part of a JUnit3 suite this way:

```
public static Test suite() {
   return new JUnit4TestAdapter(MyAppTest.class);
}
```

Usually you would add this method to the `MyAppTest` class. You could then add this test to your larger suite:

```
 public class AllTests {
   public static Test suite() {
     TestSuite suite = new TestSuite("AllTests");
     suite.addTest(MyAppTest.suite());
     ...
     return suite;
   }
}
```

You can create a JUnit4-style suite by creating a class annotated with [Suite](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runners/Suite.html)

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses( { AccountTest.class, MyAppTest.class })
public class SpringTests {}
```

Note that `AccountTest` could be a JUnit4-style test or a JUnit3-style test.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried your first suggestion and it worked! I was expecting Spring had its own test suite as written by Rod Johnson. But maybe he meant differently.