# How to create a TestSuite with parameterized spring Junit tests

Tags: spring, testing, junit

I am trying to bundle my tests in a TestSuite which will pick up files from a directory and run each one after loading spring context.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/META-INF/spring/context-test.xml"})
public class MyTestCase extends TestCase{

    private String fileName;

    public MyTestCase(String fileName){
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    @Resource private Processor processor;

    @Before
public void setup(){
    ...
    }

    @Test
    public void test(){
    Read file and run test..
    ...
    }

}
```

If I do this, it doesn't recognize spring annotations

```
public class MyTestSuite extends TestCase{

    public static Test suite(){
        TestSuite suite = new TestSuite();
        suite.addTest(new MyTestCase("file1"));
        suite.addTest(new MyTestCase("file2"));
        return suite;
    }
}
```

I looked it up and found: [Spring 3+ How to create a TestSuite when JUnit is not recognizing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691361/spring-3-how-to-create-a-testsuite-when-junit-is-not-recognizing-it) , which suggests that I should use JUnit4TestAdapter. Problem with JUnitTestAdapter is that it doesn't allow me to pass in parameters and also would not take MyTestSuite.suite(). I can only do something like:

```
public class MyTestSuite{

    public static Test suite(){

        return new JUnit4TestAdapter(MyTestCase.class);
    }
}
```

Your response is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to use deprecated AbstractSingleSpringContextTests to achieve this. AbstractSingleSpringContextTests is from the times when TestContext framework was not available.

```
public class MyTestCase extends AbstractSingleSpringContextTests {

    private String fileName;

    public MyTestCase(String fileName){
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    @Resource private Processor processor;

    @Override
    protected void onSetUp(){

         initialization code...

    }

    @Override
    protected String getConfigPath(){
         return "config/File/Path";
    }

    @Test
    public void test(){
    Read file and run test..
    ...
    }

}


public class MyTestSuite extends TestCase{

    public static Test suite(){
        TestSuite suite = new TestSuite();
        suite.addTest(new MyTestCase("file1"));
        suite.addTest(new MyTestCase("file2"));
        return suite;
    }
}
```

Its not the best solution, but it works. Please post if you have a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

Recently found [this](http://www.javathinking.com/2011/09/junit-parameterized-test-with-spring-autowiring-and-transactions/) solution. In my opinion slightly better since it doesn't rely deprecated code.